# Framework for catching Android/iPhone touch actions? - Javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, android, touch, mobile-safari

**any good framework I can use to listen for touch, swipes and pinch actions?**

---

Ideas would be awesome! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jqTouch](http://jqtouch.com/).

Comment: thanks for that!! =) I hope it's not too heavy compared to the simple functionality I need to add. Thanks again =D

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.sencha.com/. It seems pretty cool.

Comment: Yes it is, but the license forces me to open source whatever I do with it?

Comment: I think if your project is open source you can use it as you wish, but if your project is a commercial one then you would need to buy a license.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a framework, but you might find my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302000/how-to-add-a-gesture-recognizer-to-a-uiwebview-subclass/3631475#3631475) helpful. It's a working example of how to handle pinch actions in the javascript of a UIWebView. Not too inconvenient.