# How to add a gesture recognizer to a UIWebView subclass?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uigesturerecognizer

If I add a gesture recognizer to a subclassed `UIWebView` instance called `webView`, e.g.:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *_longPressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(webViewGestureRecognized:)];
_longPressRecognizer.allowableMovement = 20;
_longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 1.0f;
[webView addGestureRecognizer:_longPressRecognizer];
[_longPressRecognizer release], _longPressRecognizer = nil;
```

The `-webViewGestureRecognized:` selector is not called when I perform a long press.

I have overridden the delegate method `-gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` but the long-press selector is still not called.

```
- (BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

Is there anything I can do to enable my own gesture recognizer on the web view?

Comment: Have you solved this issue?I am also working on the same issue...Please help me ip you have solved it..

Comment: It works for me. Have you tried *not setting* allowableMovement and minimumPressDuration ? Why _longPressRecognizer = nil ? Not clear.

Comment: Could you please post the answer if you have solved this issue? I am also looking for the same. Your reply would be appreciated.

Comment: try this: https://github.com/theniceboy/HoldToSaveImage

Answer (score 5):

as far as I know UIWebView shouldnt be subclassed as mentioned in Apple docs:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 4):

Just thought I would add the answer if anyone comes back to here. 
You have not assigned the delegate, therefore `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` is not called.

```
_longPressRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

Do this and it works well.

Answer (score 2):

You should use javascript in the UIWebView to detect the gestures. (You can then communicate that back to the Objective-C if you need to.) These are [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/iad/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) on detecting gestures and touches in Javascript. I also found this [article](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/10/touching-and-gesturing-on-the-iphone/) helpful, although he uses a javascript library to deal with event binding, etc.

Here's a working example of pinching to zoom on a UIWebView that stands alone.

*Note that it is the body element is listening for the event. On a short page it appears not to catch it if you do the event in the vast un-rendered whitespace below. (If anyone knows more about it, please leave a comment.)*

```
<body id='body'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    body = document.getElementById('body');

    // (in percents)
    zoom = 100;
    maxZoom = 200;
    minZoom = 50;
    zoomIncrement = 25;

    function gestureEnd(event) {
        var newZoom;
        if (event.scale > 1.0) {
            // increase size
            newZoom = zoom + zoomIncrement;
        } else {
            // decrease size
            newZoom = zoom - zoomIncrement;
        }

        // don't exceed zoom boundaries
        if (newZoom > maxZoom || newZoom < minZoom) {
            return;
        }
        zoom = newZoom;
        body.style.webkitTextSizeAdjust = zoom+"%";
    }

    body.addEventListener("gestureend", gestureEnd, false);

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't have control over the web content, so this is not helpful for my use case.

Comment: Could you inject a `<script>` tag to include your own javascript file?

Comment: @Alex Reynolds you could just call `[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptString]` to inject it.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
return YES;
}
```