# Touch event propagation through web view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have a web view in my iphone app. It has a few links and i should allow my users to click my links.  But I also must provide them the option of moving the entire web view.

This is what I want to do:
On long press, the event is intercepted by the native code and it allows me to reposition the web view
For normal touch presses, the event is intercepted by the web view and it is possible to click the links in the web view using the normal touch.

My problem:
The webview seems to intercept all the touches.  Hence I cannot propagate the long presses to my application to reposition the webview

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: SO: [How to add a gesture recognizer to a UIWebView subclass?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302000/how-to-add-a-gesture-recognizer-to-a-uiwebview-subclass

Comment: That should be an answer, not a comment. Something seems to be up with SO.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a [UILongPressGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to your web view?