# UIWebview Gesture iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiwebview

How can I identify the user `touch`, `tap` & `double tap` in the UIWebview. Is there any delegates available like touches begin etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is the code to implement the single tap and double tap on webview

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(doSingleTap)] autorelease];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1; 
[self.myWebView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];


UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(doDoubleTap)] autorelease];
doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2; 
[self.myWebView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
```

Comment: How can I identify user tapped single or twice. Is there any delegates?

Answer (score 0):

The below 3 links will solve your problem

[how-to-add-a-gesture-recognizer-to-a-uiwebview-subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302000/how-to-add-a-gesture-recognizer-to-a-uiwebview-subclass/3631475#3631475)

[iphone-custom-gestures-on-your-uiwebview](http://fr.ivolo.us/posts/iphone-custom-gestures-on-your-uiwebview)

[does-uigesturerecognizer-work-on-a-uiwebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909807/does-uigesturerecognizer-work-on-a-uiwebview)

About number of taps, you can set it through the property **numberOfTapsRequired**

Eg:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *myGusture = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(doTap)] autorelease];
myGusture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1; //you can change it to any number as per your requirement.
[self.myWebView addGestureRecognizer:myGusture];
[myGusture release];
myGusture = nil;
```