# UIWebview zooming with word wrap

Tags: ios, uiwebview, pinchzoom

I've read through many questions with webview and zooming, but it seems that none of them adresses the problem I'm dealing with.

In my uiwebview the user can zoom in through pinching, but then the user has to pan around to see the entire content which is a no-go for me. What i want is, that after pinching, the text in the webview is rewrapped.

I tried probably all combinations setting and unsetting:

```
in the html of the webview: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=8.0; user-scalable=1;">    
in Objective-C: setScalesPageToFit:NO and YES
```

and a javascript solution described in: [How to add a gesture recognizer to a UIWebView subclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302000/how-to-add-a-gesture-recognizer-to-a-uiwebview-subclass)

...and in any solution the user has to pan around.

Has anybody solved this problem?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?